# Classes - Attribute error

Tags: python

I am currently working through the book Learn Python 3 The Hard Way.

I have reached exercise 43 where a small text adventure game is written to practice Object Oriented programming.

I completed typing in the code for the program and got it working without any errors. Then in the additional study section, the author asked for a simple combat system to be added to the script.

The full script can be seen at this link, I did not want to paste the whole script for ex43 into this question.

https://github.com/ubarredo/LearnPythonTheHardWay/blob/master/ex43.py

I created the following script as a combat system:

```
import random
import time


class Player:

    def __init__(self, hit_points, sides):
        self.hit_points = hit_points
        self.sides = sides

    def take_hit(self):
        self.hit_points -= 2

    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)


class Combat(Player):

    def combat_start():

        p = Player(hit_points = 10, sides = 6)
        e = Player(hit_points = 8, sides = 6)

        battle = 1
        while battle != 0:
            human = p.roll() + 6
            print("Your hit score: ", human)
            monster = e.roll() + 6
            print("Enemy hit score: ", monster)

            if human > monster:
                e.take_hit()
                print("Your hit points remaining: ", p.hit_points)
                print("Enemy hit points remaining:", e.hit_points)
                if e.hit_points == 0:
                    battle = 0
                    print("The Enemy is Dead!!!")
                time.sleep(2)

            elif human < monster:
                p.take_hit()
                print("Your hit points remaining: ", p.hit_points)
                print("Enemy points remaining: ", e.hit_points)
                if p.hit_points == 0:
                    battle = 0
                    print("You died in Battle!!!")
                time.sleep(2)

Combat.combat_start()
```

This works fine on its own and I wanted to use it in the script from the book.

I attempted to call it from the CentralCorridor class. After the player types in "shoot" I called the script I had written by adding:

```
Combat.combat_start()
```

What I hoped would happen is the Combat class I had written would start, then when the player won it would continue to the next scene, and if the player lost it would return the Death class.

After much trying and failing, I changed the Combat class to:

```
class Combat(Scene, Player):
```

With this added the script ran then breaks out of the loop.

```
Your hit score:  12
Enemy hit score:  12
Your hit score:  10
Enemy hit score:  11
Your hit points remaining:  8
Enemy points remaining:  4
Your hit score:  10
Enemy hit score:  10
Your hit score:  12
Enemy hit score:  7
Your hit points remaining:  8
Enemy hit points remaining:  2
Your hit score:  7
Enemy hit score:  9
Your hit points remaining:  6
Enemy points remaining:  2
Your hit score:  7
Enemy hit score:  8
Your hit points remaining:  4
Enemy points remaining:  2
Your hit score:  9
Enemy hit score:  10
Your hit points remaining:  2
Enemy points remaining:  2
Your hit score:  10
Enemy hit score:  9
Your hit points remaining:  2
Enemy hit points remaining:  0
The Enemy is Dead!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex43.py", line 220, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "ex43.py", line 24, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

If the enemy players score is higher the loop break after one or two rounds.

I'm struggling to find a solution to this and would really appreciate some pointers of where I'm going wrong.

Looking through other answers, I have seen some comment that this is not an ideal way of writing OOP in Python.

In the book it shows:

```
class Scene(object):
```

And from what I have read this is the Python 2 style of OOP. I have seen that the Author is more of a Python 2 fan than Python 3.
I do enjoy the exercises he has put into the book and want to continue onto his next one.

Any help as always will be very much appreciated.

----UPDATE----

this is the Play method as requested:

```
def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        # be sure to print out the last scene
        current_scene.enter()
```

Comment: `class Scene(object):` and `class Scene:` are exactly the same in Python 3.  The line that's failing is `next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()`, which isn't in the code you posted.  You should probably post your `play` method, so we can see what's actually happening there (`current_scene` is `None`, and it shoudn't be).

Comment: Posted the code as requested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. After writing,

```
Combat.combat_start()
```

I needed to enter:

```
return 'laser_weapon_armory'
```

without that the program was crashing as it had no-where to go next.

Also fixed the logic in the Combat class.

Thanks for the help with this.